# Problem with a Syntax in Python on a port scanner

Tags: python, sockets, port, scanning

I have a problem with a portscanner that I'm tryin' to code, It gives me an error of Syntax, let me show you the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
from termcolor import colored

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

host=input("[*] Inserisci l'indirizzo:")

def portscanner(port):
        if socket.connect_ex((host, port)):
                print (colored("[!!]La porta %d è aperta")% (port), 'red')
        else:
                print (colored("[+]La porta %d è chiusa")% (port), 'green')
for port in range(1,1000):
                portscanner(port)
```

The errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portscanner2.py", line 17, in <module>
    portscanner(port)
  File "portscanner2.py", line 12, in portscanner
    if socket.connect_ex((host, port)):
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'connect_ex'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a syntax error, that's an attribute error. Those are different beasts.

[There is no `connect_ex` function in the `socket` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html); there [is one on socket *objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex).

That is, you *may* want to change that to `sock.connect_ex()`(though you should also remember to close the socket if it's successful), or instead of initializing the `sock` once, you could use [`socket.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) to try and connect a TCP socket.

Answer (score 1):

As you've initialized it with

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

You just need to swap out `socket` for `sock`, this should do the trick!

```
if sock.connect_ex((host, port)):
```